# iOS:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (_NSInlineData)'

Tags: ios, json, nsurlsession

```
NSData *imgData;
if (!_groupImageView.image)
{
    imgData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Replay.png"])];
}
else
{
    imgData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_groupImageView.image)];
}
NSError *error;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@groups/create",[sharedObj getSiteUrl]]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:sharedObj.acessToken, @"tocken",  _txtGroupName.text, @"name",imgData, @"image",  nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```

I'm getting this exception when I try to JSON encode image data,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write
>   (_NSInlineData)'

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: (Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes.  And while you're there, note that there is no JSON entity which corresponds to an NSData object.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or by changing the imgData into string using base64EncodedString;

```
NSData *imgData;
if (!_groupImageView.image)
{
    imgData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Replay.png"])];
}
else
{
    imgData=[NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_groupImageView.image)];
}
```

//Change the image data into base64EncodedString

```
NSString *base64=[imgData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSError *error;
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:[ NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@groups/create",[sharedObj getSiteUrl]]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

//add base64 as value for key "image"

```
NSDictionary *mapData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:sharedObj.acessToken, @"tocken",  _txtGroupName.text, @"name",base64, @"image",  nil];
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:mapData options:0 error:&error];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```